# android - How to get a iBecon detection state when I kill app from Background?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an app for iBeacon BLE Bluetooth device.

In this app I want to detect ibeacon when my app kill from background also, Please help for how to do this.

I make a service but it's detect iBeacon when my app in Background, But when i kill my app from Background it's not detect becon.

I tried but not getting output if you can do this type of work help me to resolve this issue.

Thank in Advance.

Comment: Do I get you right? Your app should detect something even when it is killed?

Comment: @WernerHenze yes Right.